# Different HTML loaded after reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I'm having an issue in my Ruby on Rails application. I have a page with two forms on it. When loading the page with turbolinks (so through clicking another link to it from a page in my app), the second form doesn't load. When I refresh the page to load it cleanly, the form loads. Any idea what might cause this?

Cheers,

Stefan

Comment: Are you using a client-side framework like Ember.js? And can you post some code?

Comment: I am not and which code would you like to see? HTML?

Comment: Actually, I'm using Bootstrap and simple_form.

Answer (score 0):

With turbolink it restrict the page to be reload, so necessary css will not be compiled again, but on pageload it will compile that css.

You can take reference from here -
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Comment: The CSS doesn't seem to be the issue (nor the JS) as the HTML that's supposed to load doesn't actually load. It looks like it's loading an older version of the page where I had messed up by trying to nest two forms.

Comment: mate i think i'm not clear getting your problem, you click on one link & another form open?, if this then i think beacuse of turbolink your second form not triggered to open, you have to learn on turbolink part.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear. I have a page (call it /lists/new) and when I get on that page, two forms should load, seperately from eachother. Unfortunately, when I get to that page from a link on another page (turbolink) the forms are nested (which makes it think it's loading an old HTML file) but when I reload the page it loads the new HTML fine.